# Как сохранять состояние при обновлении страницы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

имеется состоянии у компонента примерно такое:

```
this.state= {
   auth: false
}
```

а дальше рендеринг, который зависит от состояния:

```
render(){
   return (this.state.auth ? <Table/> : <Auth />)    
}
```

вот я добился того, чтобы состояние изменилось на `this.state.auth = true`.
При перезагрузке страницы состояние меняется обратно на исходное. 
Как сделать так, чтобы состояние при перезагрузке сохранялось?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сохранять состояние туда где она не будет удалено сразу после перезагрузки страницы. Самый легкий способ сохранить в `localStorage`.
Например это может выглядеть так:

```
this.setState({ auth: true });
localStorage.setItem('auth', 'true');
```

К сожалению `localStorage` хранит только строки, поэтому придется сравнить значение со строкой:

```
this.state = {
  auth: localStorage.getItem('auth') === 'true',
}
```

Лучшим вариантом было бы присваивать пользователю токен при аутентификации, и проверять при загрузке токен на валидность, после чего выставлять значение `auth`

Comment: Не обязательно сравнивать значение со строкой, эта *проблема* решается просто, нужно использовать `JSON.stringify` во время сохранения значения в сторэйдж, а при извлечении значения делать `JSON.parse` для полуенного значения. Попробуйте, получите объект, сохраненный ранее 